# Can I bridge if don't have any ETH?

Tags: bridge, polygon-bridge

I have a metamask wallet. I have 25.8 USDC that I want to bridge from optimism to polygon or ethereum mainet but I dont have any ETH, nor on the polygon, optimism or mainet wallet. Is this possible or should I just buy some ETH elsewhere and then send it for gas fees to my metamask wallet?

Comment: You need eth to send a transaction or make any type of contract call. Don't know of any gasless relay on optimism but if there is a service it might not be worth the cut they will take for $25. Would recommend to send eth from an exchange, and to always plan to have the native gas coin on the destination chain, if bridging a token you cannot use for gas.